# c# wpf entity Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: база-данных, wpf, datagrid, entity

Есть кнопка на основной форме (`button3_Click`), которая редактирует данные о студентах в другой форме `w2`, ошибка выскакивает на `combobox` "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//редактировать информацию
    {

        Students row = (Students)dataGrid.SelectedItem;
        Window2 w2 = new Window2();

        w2.ShowDialog();
        row.IDStudent = Convert.ToInt32(w2.textBox.Text);
        row.Surname = w2.textBox1.Text;
        row.Name = w2.textBox2.Text;
        row.AddName = w2.textBox3.Text;
        row.Birthday = w2.datepicker.SelectedDate;
        row.IDGroup = int.Parse(w2.comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());

        db.SaveChanges();
        dataGrid.Items.Refresh();

    }
```

Все остальное редактирует, подскажите пожалуйста причину возникновения ошибки?

Comment: Вы уверены, что `w2.comboBox.SelectedValue` не `null`?

Comment: @AGS17 так и есть, как это предотвратить?

Comment: сетайте туда значение, очевидно